# Read Shapefile extent with Geotools

Tags: java, shapefile, geotools

Is there any possibility to get the extent of a Shapefile using the [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org) library? 
I want to read the TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT coordinates from the SHP.

Seems like there is no kind of getExtent() method...

Comment: do you mean geotools.org or geotools.com?

Comment: geotools.org, sorry. I already updated the link. do you know any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't compiled the following but it should work.

```
File file = new File("example.shp");
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put( "url", file.toURL() );
DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);

SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource( typeName );
SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures();

ReferencedEnvelope env = collection.getBounds();
double left = env.getMinX();
double right = env.getMaxX();
double top = env.getMaxY();
double bottom = env.getMinY();
```

Answer (score 3):

thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! I only had to change the url map. this is the working code:

```
File file = new File(shpFilePath);
Map<String, URL> map = new HashMap<String, URL>();      
map.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());

DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);

// SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(shpName); this works too
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(dataStore.getTypeNames()[0]);        
SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures();

ReferencedEnvelope env = collection.getBounds();
double left = env.getMinX();
double right = env.getMaxX();
double top = env.getMaxY();
double bottom = env.getMinY();
```