# How to Display shapefile(.shp) in android map?

Tags: android

I want to create a map view using shapefile in android.how is it possible?

I have read that google maps support kml.
I even heard coverting shapefile to kml there would be chance of loosing data.

Please do help how can i do this through code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [GeoTool](http://www.geotools.org/)

Please refer [Read Shapefile extent with Geotools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888404/read-shapefile-extent-with-geotools)